# IF and ELSE inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to put an IF/ELSE statement into a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_enty_srch_attr_vals] 
    (@ENTY_ID  INT,
     @FIELD_ID INT,
     @VALUE VARCHAR(5000),
     @SQL VARCHAR(5000)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FIELD_ID = 148)
        SET nocount ON;

        SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT [GPI] FROM [GPI_ASOC] WHERE [GPI] LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' ORDER BY GPI';
        SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@VALUE', @VALUE);

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

    ELSE
        SET nocount ON;
        DECLARE @ENTY_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(500)

        SET @ENTY_TABLE_NAME = (SELECT TOP 1 enty_table_name
                                FROM enty
                                WHERE enty.enty_id = @ENTY_ID)

        EXEC( 'SELECT DISTINCT ATTR_VAL  FROM '+@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+'_ATTR WHERE FIELD_ID='+@FIELD_ID+
      ' AND ATTR_VAL LIKE ''%'+@VALUE+'%'' ORDER BY ATTR_VAL ' )
END
```

I am getting this error and I have been banging my head against the wall trying to fix it.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Sp_enty_srch_attr_vals, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 17]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

What is wrong with this script?

Comment: Don't name your stored procedures with the "sp_" prefix on SQL Server.

Comment: @pmbAustin Ok, I will change them. Why?

Comment: The "sp_" prefix is used by the system for system procedures that are stored in the master database. It causes a look-up for the stored procedure in master first, and then in your current database second, so it's a performance hit.  Here are some details: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have more than one statement in an `IF` condition, then you need to use a `BEGIN-END` block

```
If <<condition>>
BEGIN 
  <<stmt 1>>
  <<stmt 2>>
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  <<stmt 3>>
  <<stmt 4>>
END
```

Also do not prefix `sp_` to your stored procedure. All the system stored procedures will be prefixed with `sp_`. Here is the articles about the problem

[Should I Use the sp_ Prefix for Procedure Names?](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/should-i-use-sp-prefix-procedure-names)

[Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 1):

You need BEGIN and END to bracket your code in the body of your IF/ELSE. You can also move the SET NOCOUNT ON to outside the IF:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Enty_srch_attr_vals] (@ENTY_ID  INT,
                                              @FIELD_ID INT,
                                              @VALUE    VARCHAR(5000),
                                              @SQL      VARCHAR(5000))
AS
BEGIN
    SET nocount ON;
      IF( @FIELD_ID = 148 )
      BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT [GPI] FROM [GPI_ASOC] WHERE [GPI] LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' ORDER BY GPI';
        SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@VALUE', @VALUE);
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        DECLARE @ENTY_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(500)
        SET @ENTY_TABLE_NAME = (SELECT TOP 1 enty_table_name
                                FROM   enty
                                WHERE  enty.enty_id = @ENTY_ID)

        EXEC( 'SELECT DISTINCT ATTR_VAL  FROM '+@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+'_ATTR WHERE FIELD_ID='+@FIELD_ID+
      ' AND ATTR_VAL LIKE ''%'+@VALUE+'%'' ORDER BY ATTR_VAL ' )
      END
END

go
```

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line IF/ELSE statements you should use a BEGIN/END block, eg.

```
  IF( @FIELD_ID = 148 )
   BEGIN
    SET nocount ON;
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT [GPI] FROM [GPI_ASOC] WHERE [GPI] LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' ORDER BY GPI';
    SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@VALUE', @VALUE);
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
   END
```